# RichText content renders only when visited from menu link but not when visited directly e.g. via hard reload

Tags: sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit app which loads external data (from hygraph) including RichText data and I have the following problem:

All works fine when I visit a page via the navigation menu link e.g.

```html
<!-- lib/Header.svelte - Header component code -->
<nav>
  <!-- ... -->
  <a href="/about">About</a>
  <!-- ... -->
</nav>
<!-- rest of Header component code -->
```

However, when I visit that url (`/about`) directly e.g. by hard reloading the page from that url, some content disappears! In particular: `{@html content.text.html}` does not show anymore. The loading part still works, as the raw `{content.text.html}` does show i.e. if I remove *@html*.

Actually `{@html content.text.html}` does flash-appear for a sec and then disappears. Below some stripped-down parts of the relevant code:

```js
// routes/+layout.js
export const prerender = true;
```

```js
// routes/about/+page.js
import { gql } from 'graphql-request'
import { client } from '$lib/graphql-client';
const query = `
  content(where: { slug: "about" }) {
    text {
      html
    }
  }
  biographies {
    text {
      html
    }
  }`;
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export const load = async () => {
  const { content, biographies } = await client.request(query)
  return { content, biographies }
}
```

```html
<!-- routes/about/+page.svelte -->
<script>
    export let data;
</script>
  <!-- other markup -->
    <div class="">
        <p class="text-justify">
            {@html data.content.text.html} <!-- this disappears -->
        </p>
        <p class="text-justify">
            {data.content.text.html} <!-- this shows -->
        </p>
    </div>
  <!-- other markup -->
```

Comment: Would not recommend pre-rendering a page that is filled with dynamic data. Though the observed behavior might still be a bug in Svelte/Kit.

Comment: @H.B. I noticed also that when I refresh the page the tittle tag reverts back to the one defined in my +layout which means that something is off there in my svelte:head tag. Not sure it's related but the change when loading is complete is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1540#issuecomment-1586303159)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just the enclosing `p` tag... Apparently `{@html ... }` also renders a p which results in nested paragraphs. All is well when I replace the enclosing tag with, say, a `div`